# Angular MVC app: Services go where?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been using angular for a few months now and understand it pretty well. I've always struggled with the MVC pattern, but for this next app I am working on, I am determined to knock that wall down.

I have my app setup like

```
index.html
/resources
    app.js
    /models
    /views
    /controllers
```

My question right now is where is the "correct" area to put services? For example, my first view is a login screen.

I need to make a service call out to a web service to login from `LoginController.js`

Right now I am putting the Service inside `app.js` like so

```
VforumJS.factory('LoginService', function($rootScope, $http)
{
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    return {
        login: function($email, $password)
        {
            data = {
                'type' : 'login',
                'email' : $email,
                'password' : $password
            };

            $http.post('resources/request.php', data, {timeout:20000})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('LoginComplete',{result:data});
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                    log(status + ', data:" ' + data + '"');
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

When I get a response back from the web service, I then do a `$rootScope.$broadcast` that my `LoginController.js` is listening for.

My other though was to create a services folder and store services in there. Any suggestions?

Comment: See the `Model Layer` section in this post. https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw

Comment: Thanks @Shiva, I looked online but was having a hard time finding the right answer. It seems there is no "right" answer, more like a best practice answer. I'll give this a read

Comment: Exactly! There is usually no "right" answer because the answer depends on the several factors that are/will-be specific to your particular project, infrastructure constraints, deployment constraints, technology stack, existing "best practices" etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 3 differents way to organize your files and your services.

- Monolithic files
- Monolithic folders
- Organizate by feature

[Here](https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw) you will find your answer. Scroll down to the "File Organization" section. It is an excellent article.

I hope it will help !